# Pass output array of one Lambda function to another function

Tags: python, arrays, aws-lambda, invoke

I have an AWS Lambda function (`Function1`) in Python 3.8. It scans an S3 bucket and lists the names of all objects into an array. I need to send this array to another Lambda function (`Function2`), which is also written in Python 3.8.

`Function1`:

```
for each in contents:
    print(each["Key"])
    inputForInvoker.append({'SQLFilename': each["Key"]})
response = lambdac.invoke(
            FunctionName='arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:169697352176:function:pyodbc',
            InvocationType='RequestResponse',
            Payload=json.dumps(inputForInvoker)
            )
```

where `contents` variable is an array of dictionaries. Example of an array element from `contents` is given below for reference. From this, I am trying to retrieve `Key` value. This logic works well because, when I print `inputForInvoker`, it gives me the array of dictionaries.

Content of `contents`:

```
{'Key': 'body_aus.sql', 'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 8, 1, 34, 12, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'ETag': '"xxx"', 'Size': 23, 'StorageClass': 'STANDARD', 'Owner': {'ID': 'yyy'}},
```

Output of `print(inputForInvoker)`:

```
[{'SQLFilename': 'body_aus.sql'}, {'SQLFilename': 'footer.sql'}, {'SQLFilename': 'header.sql'}, {'SQLFilename': 'test.sql'}]
```

`Function2`:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
sqlFileName = event['SQLFileName']
print(sqlFileName)
```

Output of `Function2`:

```
{'SQLFilename': 'body_aus.sql'}
```

I should be ideally getting the entire array from the `Function1` instead of just one element.

Comment: Event should be a dictionary object and not a list. Use `Payload=json.dumps({"queries": inputForInvoker})`

Comment: Worked well.. Thank you @OluwafemiSule!